# Substitute for Accent Seasoning

Tags: substitutions

My recipe calls for 1-teaspoon of Accent and I do not have this ingredient, as they were out of it at my grocery store.  Is there a good substitute?

Comment: What are you making? Accent is essentially monosodium glutimate.  Glutimates are naturally occurring in many ingredients. With a specific dish in mind we can offer more precise feedback.

Comment: Depending on the other seasoning, you might be able to swap those out for a seasoning blend that includes those and includes MSG.

Answer (score 6):

Accent seasoning seems to be mostly Monosodium Glutamate (MSG). You can try to find another MSG-type seasoning in your normal store (I don't know what brands might be available where you are so just look for things with MSG as the main ingredient), find pure MSG which is sometimes available in Asian grocery stores, or you could just add a cube of bouillon or two to help round out the flavour a bit.

MSG basically tastes a little salty and helps make the flavour fuller or more intense. Bouillon does the same thing, so it would be an acceptable substitute in most dishes.

Comment: Many supermarkets in the US ships Sazón GOYA, which is a MSG plus spices mix with the caveat that it tends to dye food red to orange.

Answer (score 4):

"Accent Seasoning" is [Monosodium Glutamate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monosodium_glutamate) (MSG): It looks like salt and is predominantly and originally, but not exclusively, used in Chinese & other East Asian cuisine. It's a 'flavour enhancer' in the same way salt is and has a similar but not identical purpose.

Look for an unbranded variety (supermarket's own, etc). It's very much like salt & isn't much more expensive unless it has a brand name attached to it.
There is nothing "special" about branded versions, like buying a brand name at $£€ 3.00 instead of supermarket paracetamol for $£€ 0.30

If you can't find MSG, regular salt will do at a push, [though it is not the same], at about 1:1 ratio... though to be wise, start with less. *You can always add more at the end, you can't take any back out.*

Comment: Accent also contains other ingredients, including chili pepper, cumin, and oregano.  But, yes, perhaps the most important ingredient is indeed the MSG.